# correct syntax postgresql query with two conditions, rails, eula acceptance / version test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, devise, authorization

At time of login, I am trying to evaluate whether or not a user has accepted our current end user license agreement ( eula ).

In the `contracts-controller.rb`

```
def eula_version
  eula_version = "3" 
end
```

In the `application_controller.rb`, an [after_sign_in_path_for(resource)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out) method per the devise gem instructions

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if @user = current_user
    active_user = current_user.contracts.select("user_id")
    if Contract.where(:user_id == active_user_id).where(eula_version: "3" )
      user_home_path
    else
      user_terms_path
    end
...
```

A new record is established when a user accepts our eula.  It's tagged with the eula version number by a hidden field in the acceptance form (view):

```
f.hidden_field :eula_version, :value => '3' %>
```

If I test (1) `Contract.where(:user_id == active_user_id)` in the rails console, I get the user's records, here eula_version 1 and 2.  If I test (2) `Contract..where(eula_version: "3" )`, I get an empty record: `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

So, the user has accepted eula versions 1 and 2, but not 3.  Yet if I sign in again, I'm passed to the `user_home_path` which means that `Contract.where(:user_id == active_user_id).where(eula_version: "3" )` isn't failing and pushing the user to the else statement and the `user_terms_path`.

I tried variations such as:

```
Contract.where((:user_id == active_user_id) && (eula_version: "3" ))  

Contract.where((:user_id == active_user_id) && (eula_version: "3" )) == true

Contract.where((:user_id == active_user_id) && (eula_version: "3" )).exists?
```

I obviously don't know how to evaluate two conditions that must be true.  Also, if there's a standard way to test for eula acceptance, e.g., a specific gem, I'd appreciate the reference. Thanks.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be going round in circles. Would this work?

`if current_user.contracts.find_by(eula_version: 3)`

Comment: It's now working and I'll accept your answer.  I knew I was over-thinking it!  Thanks, Doug